# How to set values in one column table by values of column in another?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables:

```
------------
| reports  |
------------
| id       |
| date     |
------------

-------------
| orders    |
-------------
| id        |
| report_id |
| old_date  |
-------------
```

I want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $report = Report::findOrFail($order->report_id);
    $order->old_date = $report->date;
    $order->save();
}
```

I want to do not get all() orders and actions in foreach(), is it possible? (Using Laravel DB)

Code result must be the same as in the example, but the way must be using SQL queries to make all actions on the DB side.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Can you clarify the expected result of your code? I think you _might_ be asking about how to make a join between the tables, but there's no little detail it's hard to be sure. See the [tour] and [ask] if you need more guidance on asking a useful question here. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider to express it in SQL directly, however this would require studying the Laravel DB component what it supports. How far did your studies went of that component already? Just asking to see more context with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible. But it's bad practice to use `foreach` or any loop for this.
Especially when you are selecting rows using `all()`.

What if row counts ecxeeds to 1k? 10k? 1M?

You can use [Structured Query Language (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) to get this done, [Laravel DB](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database) maps parts of it (see [*Database: Query Builder*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)):

```
Order::join('reports', 'reports.id', '=', 'orders.report_id')
  ->update([
    'orders.old_date' => DB::raw("reports.date")
  ]);
```

If you want to use Models & Loop for this than your code is totally right